# pass form data and a variable (ID) to a controller function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass a variable(id) along with form data to a controller function. the code is as folows

```
<form action = "index.php/my_controller/my_function" method = "POST">

   <input name = "comment" type = "text" size = "8">
   <input type = "submit" value = "save">
</form>

  <?php
     my_function($id){
                      // get the text
                      // get the id 
                      //save id and text
                     }  
  ?>
```

when I try

```
`action = "index.php/my_controller/my_function/<?php echo record['ID']?>"`
```

where $record['id'] gives me the id, the URL shows the id but HOW do i pass it to my_function($id) that is in the controller file.

Comment: Create a `hidden` field for `id ` !!

Comment: @Saty - What If someone changes value of id in HTML ?

Comment: @bugfixer that is a security issue. Can you please suggest some solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using hidden field

```
<form action = "index.php/my_controller/my_function" method = "POST">
   <input name = "id" type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
   <input name = "comment" type = "text" size = "8">
   <input type = "submit" value = "save">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry for being late. I had left office when you posted the answer.